# mysql backup from terminal : no such file or directory

Tags: ssh, terminal

I'm trying to backup the database from remote server to my laptop using terminal and ssh but after executing mysqldump I'm getting error

```
-bash: /Users/yan/projects/loc/myweb/db/mydb_db.sql: No such file or directory
```

that what I did

```
ssh root@xxx.xx.xxx.xx
```

after that

```
root@myweb:~# mysqldump -u dbusername -pdbpassword mydatabase > /Users/yan/projects/loc/myweb/db/mydb_db.sql
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that the directory is not accessible on the server. If `/Users/yan/...` is a directory on your laptop, it will not be accessible on the server, so first use a directory on the server as output for `mysqldump`, and than copy the resulting file to your laptop e.g. using [scp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp).

As an example, on the server (using a temporary folder):

```
mysqldump ... > /tmp/mydb_db.sql
```

On the laptop:

```
scp root@xxx.xx.xxx.xx:/tmp/mydb_db.sql /Users/yan/projects/loc/myweb/db/mydb_db.sql
```

Note that you should use a directory on the server where only you has access permissions.

Comment: You don’t really need a temp remote file for that, you can redirect the output of a ssh command to a local file `ssh 127.0.0.1 'echo “hello”' > ~/path/to/my/local.file` would end you having “hello” in the local file. It cannot be done in two separate commands, though, as the OP was trying to do it